# .NET Core App generate multiple websites for client

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis

I have an app with products and I want to add a new feature "generate public list of your products on your domain". How can I do that?

I have one .NET Core app with one database. I want to generate site for my client with products from my db. I don't want to manage multiple IIS websites.

My plan is create predefined design and every client can edit texts from admin. I don't know how to deal with multiple domains and one app.

Is it possible? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple domains pointing at the same application under the hood. They would need some why of knowing what different information they needed to present.

You could do this by detecting the current Domain name and using some kind of lookup table or something.

You could detect the domain name using something like this:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is it SEO friendly approach?

Comment: I believe search engines would see them all as separate websites. So they would not benefit or impact each other. Having them all on the same domain, with different URL's I believe would boost the SEO of the core domain, but it defeats your purpose you set out in the question.